# What would be the best technique for website localization in MVC?

Tags: .net, mvc, internationalization, localization

Currently I'm working on a big website that will be published on almost 40 domains with different languages. My question is what would be the best way of doing localization/internationalization. I'm interested in programming technique. What have I found so far is :

- Store literals in Resource files
- Store literals Database
- Store literals on Client side

My concern is about how to do this properly. I haven't found anything about how the "big sites" do their localization. Every comment is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Things to consider.

1. How and where are resources translated.
2. How are translations obtained and used.

These are orthogonal requirements in most cases. Even if you have the ability
to translate in context ie in the web page or app where they're stored and 
managed it's not necessarily the best place to access them.

For a very high volume site you'd use a resource bundle that gets deployed with the app and is accessible using an in memory DB or in some cases ie extremely high volume web pages you'd pre generate the templates/views/assets in each language ie

```
example.com/en/index.html
example.com/fr/index.html
example.com/es/index.html
example.com/en-GB/index.html
```

This is all app/performance specific.

Comment: There is already an existing application that imports the resource files and other xml files and let translators translate it for different languages. But I think maybe there is a better solution. I also red about gettext() in linux, but this is not a key centered translation which I need. Currently a minimal localization is made with resource files, and this project is an MVC project that will be published with it's configuration files for each "domain".

Comment: What I'm saying is that `how to do this properly` depends on what you're about to do. You need to elaborate on your problem/dilema. Understanding your problem is what I'm trying to do...